# Is it possible to pass a Revealing Module Pattern instance to a callback function?

Tags: javascript, revealing-module-pattern

I have some javascript using the Revealing Module Pattern as shown below. It accepts a callback function that it later invokes. I want that callback function to then be able to call functions defined in the class, but it's not working.

```
window.MyClass = function() {
  var self = this,

  start = function (callback) {
    callback(self);
  },

  cancel = function() {
    console.log('Cancel invoked');
  };

  return {
    start: start,
    cancel: cancel
  };
};

var myCallbackFunction = function(instance) {
  instance.cancel(); // Error: instance.cancel is not a function
};

var obj = new window.MyClass();
obj.start(myCallbackFunction);
```

I can rework this sample into the Revealing Prototype Pattern and it works as expected, so my question is can I get this working using RMP, or is it just a limitation of this pattern?

Thanks,
Roger

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
window.MyClass = function() {
  var self = this;

  this.start = function (callback) {
    callback(self);
  };

  this.cancel = function() {
    console.log('Cancel invoked');
  };

  return {
    start: this.start,
    cancel: this.cancel
  };
};
```

Then, it's both an instance method, and available via the returned value.

But for something this simple (e.g. no private variables), I would use a straight-up prototype ("Prototype Pattern").

By the way, if you're reading [this series](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2011/07/31/techniques-strategies-and-patterns-for-structuring-javascript-code.aspx), you should be aware these are not really standard terms.

He also stated, "Although JavaScript isn’t designed with the concept of classes or object oriented programming in mind as with C# or Java, with a little work you can achieve similar results."  In fact, JavaScript is designed for object-oriented programming, but it's prototype-based.  It's also flexible enough to allow alternatives, as you've seen; those alternatives are definitely better in some cases.

You don't even need self, since your objects stay bound.

So:

```
window.MyClass = function(){};

window.MyClass.prototype = {
    start: function (callback) {
        callback(this);
    },

    cancel: function () {
        console.log('Cancel invoked');
    }
};


var myCallbackFunction = function(instance) {
  instance.cancel();
};

var obj = new window.MyClass();
obj.start(myCallbackFunction);
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured it was possible - I just wasn't figuring out the syntax.

Comment: The first example is sort of misleading, for reasons I describe in my answer. You aren't getting a real instance of `MyClass` at all. But also in this example, it doesn't matter. But it's an important detail to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Never return an object from a constructor. This is one of those weird JS quirks.

You aren't getting an instance of `MyClass`, you are getting a plain object. When a contructor returns an object, that object is returned *instead of* the instance that would have been returned.

```
// good!
function MyClass() {};
new MyClass().constructor // returns: function MyClass() {}
new MyClass().constructor == MyClass // true

// bad!
function MyClass() { return {a:123}; };
new MyClass().constructor // returns: function Object() { [native code] }
new MyClass().constructor == MyClass // false
```

In short, classical style and revealing module style don't mix well.

In your case, any function assign to a property of `this` is you revealing that function to the outside.  So maybe you wanted this instead.

```
window.MyClass = function() {
  var self = this;

  var start = function (callback) {
    callback(self);
  };

  var cancel = function() {
    somePrivateFn();
    console.log('Cancel invoked');
  };

  var somePrivateFn = function() {
    console.log('private function!');
  };

  this.start = start;
  this.cancel = cancel;
};
```

---

But if you don't need anything private (your example reveals everything, so nothing remains private) use a prototype based approach like Matthew suggests, which is faster and simpler in all regards.